Reproducing PCA results of pca.fit_transform() using pca.fit()?
I have a data frame called data_principal_components with dimensions (306x21154), so 306 observations and 21154 features. Using PCA, I want to project the data into 10 dimensions.
As far as I understand, the following code does this. The resulting matrix (projected) has a dimension of (306x10).
#Sample data:
# Define the dimensions of the DataFrame
num_rows = 306
num_cols = 21154

# Generate random numbers from a normal distribution
data = np.random.randn(num_rows, num_cols)

# Create a DataFrame from the random data
data_principal_components = pd.DataFrame(data)


pca = PCA(10)  
projected = pca.fit_transform(data_principal_components)

To have a better feeling how the code proceeds I wanted to reproduce the result of the pca.fit_transform() "manually".
Based on internet search I found that:
pc_components = pca.components_ #This gives the eigenvectors
pc_components = pc_components.transpose() #Transposes the eigenvectors, so one has the dimensions (21154x10)
eigenvalues = pca.explained_variance_ #These are the eigenvalues with dimensions (1x10)

Now, as far as I understood one can calculate the loadings using the following code based on the formula $  loadings = eigenvectors * 
 sqrt(eigenvalues) $
# Create an empty DataFrame
df = pd.DataFrame()

# Iterate over eigenvalues
for i in range(len(eigenvalues)):
    result = np.dot(pc_components[:, i], np.sqrt(eigenvalues[i]))
    df[f'Result_{i+1}'] = result  # Assign result as a new column in the DataFrame
    
loadings = df

After obtaining the loadings with the dimensions (21154x10), I wanted to use them to obtain the projected values with $Actual values*loadings$
with the dimensions (306x21154)*(21154x10)=(306x10):
test = np.dot(data_principal_components,loadings)

However, when I compare test to projected, the values differ substantially. Where am I wrong?
